# Defining tuple data types in the function signature on F#

Tags: f#, tuples

I want to define the expected data type of the elements of a tuple which will be passed to call a function. When I don't define it and let the type inference work it is ok, but in the moment I want to write small functions that are still not called anywhere I don't get how to define the arguments.

This example. I expect `description` to be a tuple where every of the five elements is a `int` and then extract each of the parts to work with then.

```
let setArray (description: int * int * int * int * int)  =
    let id = fun (i, _, _, _, _) -> i
    let startX = fun (_, x, _, _, _) -> x
    let startY = fun (_, _, y, _, _) -> y
    let width = fun (_, _, _, w, _) -> w
    let height = fun (_, _, _, _, h) -> h
    let arrayResult = Array2D.init (width + 1) (height + 1) (fun i j -> if i < width &&  j < height then id)
    arrayResult
```

> .fsx(29,45): error FS0001: The type 'int' does not match the type ''a * 'b * 'c * 'd * 'e -> 'd'

For other functions, like I said, type inference works and I can use the pattern matching without problem

```
let getMaxCoords =
    let x = elements |> Seq.map (fun (_, x, _, _, _) -> x) |> Seq.max
    let y = elements |> Seq.map (fun (_, _, y, _, _) -> x) |> Seq.max
    x, y
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The errors are raised by the code after `Array2D.init`, not the signature. They complain because `id`, `startX` etc are *functions* that work on tuples, not integers. You could write `height description` and get the last element from `description`

Comment: `width` is a function, so `(width + 1)` is a type error. It looks like you want to destructure the tuple argument to `setArray` i.e. `let setArray (id, startX, startY, width, height)) = ...`. If you do that, the init function you're passing to `Array2D.init` needs to return a value in an `else` branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the following code block is defining five *functions*, not five integer values:

```
let setArray (description: int * int * int * int * int)  =
    let id = fun (i, _, _, _, _) -> i
    let startX = fun (_, x, _, _, _) -> x
    let startY = fun (_, _, y, _, _) -> y
    let width = fun (_, _, _, w, _) -> w
    let height = fun (_, _, _, _, h) -> h
```

What you probably meant to do is to pass the `description` tuple into each of these destructuring functions, like so:

```
let setArray (description: int * int * int * int * int)  =
    let id = description |> (fun (i, _, _, _, _) -> i)
    let startX = description |> (fun (_, x, _, _, _) -> x)
    let startY = description |> (fun (_, _, y, _, _) -> y)
    let width = description |> (fun (_, _, _, w, _) -> w)
    let height = description |> (fun (_, _, _, _, h) -> h)
```

But there's a much easier way to do this. F# lets you destructure a tuple in the function signature. So you can replace that whole code block with the following:

```
let setArray (id, startX, startY, width, height) =
```

That's it! So now your entire function looks like:

```
let setArray (id, startX, startY, width, height) =
    let arrayResult = Array2D.init (width + 1) (height + 1) (fun i j -> if i < width && j < height then id)
    arrayresult
```

And there's one more simplification you can make. Any time you have `let x = (some calculation)` followed immediately by `x` as the function's return value, you can get rid of that `let` and just have the function return `(some calculation)`. Applying that simplification, your function becomes:

```
let setArray (id, startX, startY, width, height) =
    Array2D.init (width + 1) (height + 1) (fun i j -> if i < width && j < height then id)
```

And you're done! If you really want to specify that `id`, `startX`, etc., are all integers, you can do it like this:

```
let setArray (id : int, startX : int, startY : int, width : int, height : int) =
    Array2D.init (width + 1) (height + 1) (fun i j -> if i < width && j < height then id)
```

Comment: Thanks for such a complete answer! I am still learning how to simplify the functions correctly.

Comment: One more thing: I just noticed that this code still won't compile, because there's no `else` branch in the `if i < width ...` expression. In F#, any `if` expression that doesn't have an `else` is assumed to have `else ()` at the end. Furthermore, all `if` expressions *must* return the same type for both the true and false branches; since `()` has the type `unit` which does not match `int`, your code won't compile as-is. You'd need to add `else 0`, so that the `if` becomes `if i < width && j < height then id else 0`.

Comment: Yes, I saw that also and just added a default value for the grid.